# PHP / SimpleXML - Adding a Child node under Root without inheriting parent namespace

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to add a child node under the Root node however it prefixes the new child node with the Root/Parent NS.  How can I simply add a new child node without the Root/Parent NS?

```
<?php
$file = 'file.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$number = $xml->addChild('ANumber', "12345");

$xml->asXML($file);

exit; 

?>`
```

Comment: There's an optional `namespace` argument to `addChild()`, you can use that to specify a different namespace.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!  This resolved my issue, I was missing the third parameter so was inheriting the parent NS.  Added a blank "" 3rd parameter in the addChild.  Thanks again